# How to move certain types of files to other directory with a Python script

Tags: python, file, subprocess, call, move

My code is:

```
subprocess.call(["mv", "*.fasta", f"{my_model_dir}/."])
```

And the error code I got was:

```
mv: cannot stat '*.fasta': No such file or directory
```

I tried moving all the fasta files to other directory, but, I got an error message.

I think it's because the '*' is used as a regular expression in Python, so it's not working in this situation. To move files with a Python script to other directory, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages.  Grammar is important on SO, so please avoid things like "plz" and use proper capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

try `subprocess.call(["mv", "\*.fasta", f"{my_model_dir}/."])`

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.